# List converted to Dropdown in Flask/WTForms

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Basically I have a list in Python and would like to programmatically call on and create a dropdown form from this list using WTForms into an HTML doc.  I can't figure out what I am missing here when trying to use the **SelectField** approach in WTForms. The list is within "updatef".

I get the error:  **ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**
when trying to run this.

```
class ReusableForm(Form):  # Define the form fields and validation parameters
    updates = SelectField(u'Update Frequency', choices = updatef, validators = [validators.required()])


@app.route("/editor", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)  # calls on form

        if request.method == 'POST':
            updates = request.form['updates']
```

HTML

```
    <form  id="main" action="" method="post" role="form" spellcheck="true">
    <p> {{ form.updates }} </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choices` has to be a list of 2 value tuples such as `[(1,'Daily'),(2,'Weekly')]` - your error seems to suggest you might only have a list of values.

Comment: hmm thank you! I will look at tomorrow but that would make sense.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick.  I just needed to add the "id" primary key to the list.

Comment: So I was only able to get this working by adding coerce=int  for the SelectField parameters.  But the output is the 'ID' number chosen.  So for example my second choice is "BOB", but my output is id number, "2".  How would I get "BOB" as my output?

Comment: You could just change the key value pair, as [("daily", "daily")].